# Get the method by which AngularJS directive links to DOM element (attribute / tag name)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to find out inside a directive if it was linked to DOM by attribute, or by it's tag name?

For example:, if I have the following directive:

```
app.directive('myDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log( [link_type] ) // should be either Element or Attribute (or something similar)

        }
    }
});
```

Then, I should get something like:

```
<my-dir></my-dir> <!-- Should log 'Element' -->

<div my-dir></div> <!-- Should log 'Attribute' -->
```

The only thing I have so far is checking for attributes corresponding to certain isolated scope properties, or DOM .nodeName property, but I think this is somehow hacky, and I'm interested if there is a specialized method for this.

Comment: why do you need to do that? if you want a different behavior when for directives defined by element and directives defined by attribute, just use two directives, one with restrict: 'E' and second with restrict: 'A'

Comment: That's what I tried first, but for my case, the only thing that differs is the isolated scope properties. The rest of the logic is identical. There are ways I can avoid using this method, but I still want to know if it is possible to get the result I described above.

Comment: you can check the element in link function for occurence of attribute/tag and decide which way to go... but generally I think this is not possible within directive declaration, because the definition is basically a singleton

Comment: I tried this also, as I described in the last paragraph, and it is a working solution. Still, I'm curious if there is a built-in mechanism for that. I agree that you can't check for attributes/tags within directive factory function, because it is invoked only once per directive (first time the compiler finds a match, I believe)

Comment: Exactly, so I don't believe there is another way of dealing with it as to do it manually in linking process